# Finite State Machine Program invalid output

Tags: java, expression

I am working on a project and my code isn't working not sure why. Given the test program and general class I need a program that satisfies the following logical regular epxression:

L1: For alphabet {a,b}, all strings that contain an odd number of a's and exactly one b.

Test input: aabaaaa, aaabaaaa, aabaaaab, baaaaaa, aaaaabaa

What it should be:

aabaaaa    False

aaabaaaa    True

aabaaaab    false

baaaaaa false

aaaaabaa    True

Program output:
(ture, true, true, false, true)

My Test program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

// Test Finite State Machine Class
public class TestFSML1
{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String A = "ab";
    int[][] ST = {{1,3,0},
            {1,2,1},
            {2,2,2},
            {3,3,3}};
    int[] AS = {0,0,1,0};
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inString;
    boolean accept1 = false;
    FSM FSM1 = new FSM(A, ST, AS);

// Input string is command line parameter
    System.out.println("     Input       Accepted:");

    for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++) {
      inString = args[i];
      accept1 = FSM1.validString(inString);

      System.out.printf("%10s%13s\n",inString, accept1);
    }
  } // end main
} // end class
```

FSM Class

```
// Finite State Machine Class
public class FSM
{
  // Instance variables
  public  String alphabet;
  public  int    stateTrans[][];
  public  int    acceptState[];
  private int    cstate;

  // Constructor function

  public FSM(String A, int[][] ST, int[] AS)
  {
    int NSYMBOLS = A.length();
    int NSTATES  = AS.length;
    // Alphabet
    alphabet = "" + A;
    // State transition table
    stateTrans = new int[NSTATES][NSYMBOLS];
    for(int r = 0; r < NSTATES; r++)
      for(int c = 0; c < NSYMBOLS; c++)
        stateTrans[r][c] = ST[r][c];
    // Accept states
    acceptState = new int[NSTATES];
    for(int r = 0; r < NSTATES; r++)
      acceptState[r] = AS[r];
    // Start state
    cstate = 0;
  } 

  // Methods

  public int getState()
  {
    return cstate;
  }

  public void setState(int state)
  {
    cstate = state;
    return;
  }

  public int nextState(char symbol)
  {
    int nstate = -1;
    int col = alphabet.indexOf(symbol);
    if(col >= 0)
      nstate = stateTrans[cstate][col];
    return nstate;
  }

  public boolean accept(int state)
  {
    if(state < 0)
      return false;
    return (acceptState[state] != 0);
  }

  public boolean validString(String word)
  {
    cstate = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < word.length(); k++){
      cstate = nextState(word.charAt(k));
      System.out.print(cstate);
      System.out.println("  " + word.charAt(k));
      if(cstate < 0)
        return false;
    }
    return accept(cstate);
  }


} // end class
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple method I typed up to perform the task you wanted.

```
public static boolean validWord(String s) {

        int aCounter = 0;
        int bCounter = 0;
        char c;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            c = s.charAt(i);

            if ((int) c == (int) 'a') {

                aCounter++;
            } else {

                bCounter++;
            }
        }

        return (aCounter % 2 == 1 && bCounter == 1);
    }
```

I had trouble understanding how you were implementing your method, and I think it could be much simpler.  I'm sure the instance variables you included in the FSM class serve some other use, but I you don't really need any of them to analyze the string.  Just use something like this, it should be easy enough to integrate into your code as all it takes is the string.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah I wish I could use that as a solution. I have to use the FSM class unforunately.